# Horizontal Paging/Swipe views

Tags: android, animation, drag, swipe

I have a quiz app which loads questions into a textview, answers in radiobuttons which is wrapped in a scrollview. Currently I'm using next and previous buttons which work but I'd rather use swiping to control that. How do I implement this so that I can get animations of the page being dragged kind of like the tabs in the google play music app.

I've googled around and seen viewpager used a lot, but I don't know if that's right for what I want to do. I've also considered using viewflipper but again I don't know if that's right. And  I wouldn't know how to use either of those in an animated drag fashion.

There's the possibility of hundreds of questions one after another which might be a factor.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I implement this so that I can get animations of the page being dragged kind of like the tabs in the google play music app.

Use a `ViewPager`.

> There's the possibility of hundreds of questions one after another which might be a factor.

Rewrite your app to not ask the user "hundreds of questions one after another", then. Having a *single quiz* that long would be annoying in any medium, IMHO.

From a coding standpoint, depending upon what else is going on in your app, memory might become an issue using `ViewPager`, `ViewFlipper`, or pretty much anything other than a single set of radio buttons whose captions you change as the user moves from question to question.

Comment: Thank you :) It's an exam quiz app so it needs so many questions.